# get a specific item in DataGridViewComboBoxCell c#

Tags: c#

I have some items in my DataGridViewComboBoxCell, when the form loads i need to show a specific item in that DataGridViewComboBoxCell.

Here is the code-

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbc = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

foreach (String item in objectListBoxList[listboxNumber].GetItemInList())
{
    cbc.Items.Add(item);
}   
dataGridViewList[tableNumber].Rows[parameter.getRow()].Cells[1] = cbc;
```

I need it to be something like this---

```
dataGridViewList[tableNumber].Rows[parameter.getRow()].Cells[1] = cbc.Items[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you the codes for clicking on specific cell.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
    { 
          // Show in messagebox
           MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
          // Set the value to string
          String value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer i coded :

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbc = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
foreach (String item in objectListBoxList[listboxNumber].GetItemInList())
{
    cbc.Items.Add(item);
}
// this line sets the default item in DataGridViewComboBoxCell to be at index 0--
cbc.Value = myListBox[0];    
dataGridViewList[tableNumber].Rows[parameter.getRow()].Cells[1] = cbc;
```